# Change the position of wordpress single post featured image

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to put my featured image of each single post as a banner image for single page post. How could I do that? When I tried to display featured image it comes twice.

Comment: What did you try that caused the images to appear twice?

Comment: @JasonAller When I activate featured image for post it displayed automatically on post page which I don't want. Instead, i need to display the featured image as banner of my post page.